# scipy.signal.resample: malfunction with even number of points?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

It seems that **scipy.signal.resample()** makes errors when downsampling to an even number of points. For example, if we upsample a function to a multiple of the original points and then downsample again, we should get the original function back.

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

def test_resample(n1,n2): # upsample from n1 to n2 points and back
    x1=np.arange(n1)
    y1=np.sin(x1)
    y2,x2=signal.resample(y1,n2,x1)  
    y3,x3=signal.resample(y2,n1,x2)  
    print np.allclose(y1,y3)
```

But this fails when the lower number of points is even:

```
test_resample(10,20)
    False

test_resample(11,22)
    True

test_resample(11,33)
    True
```

The problem occurs at the downsampling step. The errors are large, at least several percent for functions I tested.

Update of 4/8/17: This really seems to be a coding error. I reported details of the bug [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7278).